# Serialize T that contains List<T>

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization, deserialization, xml-deserialization

I want to serialize a `MyClass`, which is a class that contains a list `MyClass`.

In the XML, I want to write only `myClass.Name`, then when I deserialize it, I then find which `MyClass` should be in which other `MyClass`. I have the following code that properly serializes the list of `MyClass` into a list of `string`. However, it doesn't deserialize the list of string.

```
//List of actual object. It's what I use when I work with the object.
[XmlIgnore]
public List<TaskConfiguration> ChildTasks { get; set; }

//Used by the serializer to get the string list, and used
//by the serializer to deserialize the string list to.
[XmlArray("ChildTasks")]
public List<string> ChildTasksSurrogate
{
    get
    {
        List<string> childTaskList = new List<string>();

        if (ChildTasks != null)
            childTaskList.AddRange(ChildTasks.Select(ct => ct.Name).ToList());

        if (_childTasksSurrogate != null)
            childTaskList.AddRange(_childTasksSurrogate);

        //Clears it not to use it when it serializes.
        _childTasksSurrogate = null;
        return childTaskList;
    }
    set
    {
        _childTasksSurrogate = value;
    }
}

[XmlIgnore]
private List<string> _childTasksSurrogate;
```

As I said, the serialization works. The problem lies with the deserialization. After the deserialization, `MyClass._childTasksSurrogate` is `null`.

Comment: There is the clear code that you have assign null to **childTasksSurrogate** in get accessor just before the return statement.

Comment: Where? I'm not nulling the value I'm returning. However, I think it allows me to find the problem: I took for granted that the deserialization wouldn't call the getter, and only the setter. I'll the getter and add a flag that says if the List<string> has been converted to a List<MyClass>. Thanks!

Comment: Who said that you are nulling the value that you are returning. You have assigned null to **_childTasksSurrogate** in your get accessor.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was related to HOW does the `XmlSerializer` deserializes the Xml :
I thought that the `XmlSerializer` would assign the whole property (read: `myList = DeserializedList)`, while it looks like it adds all the elements (read: `myList.AddRange(DeserializedList)`.

Comment: This doesn't really say much about how you solved your problem.  Consider adding a code snippet to illustrate your solution.